# What is the correct way to load CSS staticfiles using npm and Django?

Tags: django, django-staticfiles

I want to load my static css files (e.g., Bootstrap) from my node_modules directory, like so:

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css' %}" />
```

When I put `.../node_modules/` in my `STATICFILES_DIRS` setting, this works. However, it also adds an absolutely massive number of files to my `/static/` folder - mostly `devDependencies` that I don't need access to on the frontend.

What is the best practice for including certain static assets via npm, but not including everything from `node_modules` in my `/static/` folder?

Or, is it fine to include so many extraneous files and that's the best solution?

Comment: This looks handy: https://github.com/whitespy/django-node-assets

Answer (score 9):

What I do is the following,

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(DJANGO_PROJECT_DIR, 'static'),
    os.path.join(ROOT_DIR, 'node_modules', 'd3', 'build'),
    os.path.join(ROOT_DIR, 'node_modules', 'c3'),
)
```

This will place only the needed files in my static folder.

Comment: thanks - so you're able to add file paths here. I would have expected this to raise `OSError: [Errno 20] Not a directory` in the [storage's `listdir` method here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/967be82443b5640d61608a89897d8ce2bc44fa54/django/core/files/storage.py#L397). What is your `STATICFILES_STORAGE` setting? Also how do you add these in your template?

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake indeed. I will improve the answer. I should not load the files

Comment: I see - but then you need a separate line for each file in your template as well?

Comment: For as far as I know. Yes

Answer (score 8):

To avoid importing many unused files in the static folder, I copy the items I need with a [Gulp](https://gulpjs.com/) script. I use an [NPM script](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts) to invoke Gulp after installing the packages, so it doesn't affect my daily workflow.

#### `package.json`:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "gulp": "^4.0.2",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "install": "gulp"
  }
}
```

#### `gulpfile.js`

```
const { series, src, dest } = require('gulp');

// Task 1: copy bootstap's assets to /_vendor/
function bootstrap() {
  const files = [
    'node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css',
    'node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js'
  ]
  return src(files).pipe(dest('_vendor'))
}

// Task 2: copy jquery's assets to /_vendor/
function jquery() {
  const files = [
    'node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js'
  ]
  return src(files).pipe(dest('_vendor'))
}

exports.default = series(bootstrap, jquery)
```

#### `my_project/settings.py`:

```py
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    str(BASE_DIR / '_vendor'),  # populated by gulp
]
```

#### Django template:

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'bootstrap.min.css' %}" />
```

## Bonus

In the Gulpfile, you can concatenate and minify files. As an example, here is my Gulpfile for Blueimp's file upload library:

```
const uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
const concat = require('gulp-concat');

// Task 3: minify blueimp's assets and save to /_vendor/
function blueimp() {
  const files = [
    'node_modules/blueimp-file-upload/js/vendor/jquery.ui.widget.js',
    'node_modules/blueimp-file-upload/js/jquery.iframe-transport.js',
    'node_modules/blueimp-file-upload/js/jquery.fileupload.js'
  ]
  return src(files).pipe(uglify())
                   .pipe(concat('jquery.fileupload.min.js'))
                   .pipe(dest('_vendor/'))
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Would you add your Django template? Do you invoke gulp on local and commit the resulting concatenated JS file or do you invoke gulp as part of the build process?

Comment: @YPCrumble, I added the Django template. No, I don't commit the `_vendor` folder, because it's populated when the CI runs `npm install`. For the same reason, I don't commit `node_modules/` either. I only commit `package.json` and `gulpfile.js`.

Answer (score 3):

I personally think it's fine to have these extraneous dev files living in node_modules (and duplicated into STATIC_ROOT). Your mileage may vary if your node_modules folder is gigantic, but doubling the size isn't usually a big deal for my use cases, and it's convenient to not have to list each module in STATICFILES_DIRS as I install them.

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    ...
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'node_modules'),
    ...
)
```

Then in your templates, do:

```
<script src='{% static 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css' %}'></script>
```

If the folder ever did get out of hand size-wise, if you started encountering conflicts, or if there was a library you really didn't want to serve, Jostcrow's answer (or writing a custom staticfiles finder) could make sense.

Also, might be worth looking into trying to bundle everything together. If all of your stuff lives in bundled JS/CSS files, the whole issue is resolved by just webpack-ing those files into your app of choice.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the way I do that since [my previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57656078/1164966). Now, I use [django-npm](https://github.com/kevin1024/django-npm), a ridiculously simple package that allows cherry-picking the files you want to import from `node_modules/`.
As a comparison, here is how I could achieve the same result as in my previous response:

##### `package.json`

```json
{
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1"
  }
}
```

##### `my_project/settings.py`

```py
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
  ...
  'npm.finders.NpmFinder',  # see django-npm's installation instructions
)

NPM_STATIC_FILES_PREFIX = 'node_modules'
NPM_FILE_PATTERNS = {
    'bootstrap': [
        'dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.*',
    ],
    'jquery': [
        'dist/jquery.min.*',
    ],
}
```

##### What about concatenation and minification?

I use [django-compressor](https://github.com/django-compressor/django-compressor) and [django-sass-processor](https://github.com/jrief/django-sass-processor).